# Nodejs backend mongoose and the database connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, docker-compose

I have an issue that i'm trying to fix since yesterday.

In fact, i have a a backend that i want to connect to a MongoDB hosted on the cloud, i use Mongoose, i put a connection string `mongodb+srv://user:*********@cluster0-****.gcp.mongodb.net/pws`. I have whitelisted all ips to connect to the database.

My problem is that when i run `npm start`, it connect correctly to the database, and when i run a docker-compose (that runs the same commands), i have this error message :

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
```

i don't see what can cause this issue.. please help

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Add the docker-compose file at least.

Answer (score 0):

What I`m suggesting is :

1- Check if MongoDB is installed on your cloud

2- Check if it`s truly running on the port 27017